# Show CustomMessageBox before exit application by pressing back key

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, exit, messagebox, back

I want to show a dialog to confirm exit when user presses back key. I know it can be done by using the native MessageBox. However, when I use CustomMessageBox from winphone toolkit instead, the cancel event isn't resumed once it is canceled.

```
protected override void OnBackKeyPress(System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
    e.Cancel = true;
    CustomMessageBox messageBox = new CustomMessageBox()
        {
            Caption = "Exit",
            Message = "Do you want to exit?",
            LeftButtonContent = "Yes",
            RightButtonContent = "No"
        };
        messageBox.Dismissed += (s1, e1) =>
        {
            switch (e1.Result)
            {
                case CustomMessageBoxResult.LeftButton:
                  //app doesn't exit as expected
                    e.Cancel = false;
                    break;
                case CustomMessageBoxResult.RightButton:
                    break;
                case CustomMessageBoxResult.None:
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        };      
    messageBox.Show();
}
```

If I don't cancel the event, the app will exit without showing the messagebox. If I try to call Show then lock the thread, the messagebox will not be displayed. I know I can exit app by using Terminate or exception instead but I also want it to exit properly so Application_Closing can be called. Please help! Thank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the custom messagebox, then you have no other choice than canceling the back event. And if you do, then you have to exit pro grammatically the application, with the issue you mentioned.

There's no way out of that one. You need to free the UI thread so CustomMessageBox can display its controls, and that thread won't be free until you've exited the `OnBackKeyPress` event. Just stick to the native messagebox, it's for the best.

Comment: thank for answering, but I need to use the CustomMessageBox to customize the semi-transparent screen color in light theme

Comment: @MadiShiva Then you have no other choice than canceling the back key event then forcefully exiting the application, with the drawbacks you mentioned. If `Application_Closing` not being called is your sole worry, refactor your code to move the logic to another method, then call this method from both `Application_Closing` and the callback method of the messagebox

Comment: Yeah, it seems the only way if there are no other solutions

Answer (score 2):

I found this post, and apply it successfully with my situation.
[Using the CustomMessageBox in OnBackKeyPressed](http://metronuggets.com/2013/06/11/using-the-custommessagebox-in-onbackkeypressed/)

Comment: Thanks for sharing but that's not my case. My problem is I want to exit the app properly (which triggers `Application_Closing`) after showing CustomMessageBox.